# What is the difference, if any, between these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, present-tense

**What is the difference, if any, between the following two sentences?**

> (1) The sun sets at 9 P.M. tomorrow.
>
> (2) The sun is setting at 9 P.M. tomorrow.

Comment: I'd say with both of those you'd need the definite article "the" at the beginning, and semantically they mean the same thing. If you wanted a better way to say it I'd perhaps go with "Sunset is at 9 P.M. tomorrow."

Comment: In addition to adding *the* as the previous comment suggests, you also should make them future tense- *will set* or *will be setting* respectively.  After that, as said, the meanings are identical.

Comment: @JohnClifford thanks for pointing out the missing articles (I'm not a native speaker). I would like to get a detailed answer from a native speaker. I'm sure you're one, so please post an answer if you can.

Comment: @cobaltduck so, the second one does not sound weird to a native speaker's ear?

Comment: @user132181:  Yes, it does.  If you change to "The sun is setting right now" (present tense) or "The sun will be setting at 9pm tomorrow" (future tense) then it will be fine.

Comment: @user132181 Done!

Comment: The biggest difference is that you'd probably only encounter #2 from a speaker of *Indian English*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically they mean the same thing, though

> The sun is setting at 9 P.M. tomorrow.

Might throw up red flags for some people as it should really use future tense:

> The sun will set/will be setting at 9 P.M. tomorrow.

However, it's technically acceptable as a colloquial-ish usage: it's not dissimilar to saying something like "My test results are arriving at noon tomorrow." Not massively common usage, but some people do say it like that.

If you want to make it completely unambiguous, you could instead say

> Sunset will be at 9 P.M. tomorrow.

(Credit to cobaltduck for the point about future tense)

Comment: Thank you for the meaningless internet points! :D And you're welcome.

Comment: Your assertion that it *really should use future tense* is not helpful here. This is a standard use of the present continuous. There's no requirement to use the modaql verb *will* here.